# Custom menu with floating text and asymmetric sides

Tags: php, html, css, menu, bootstrap-4

I'd like to make a menu for my website that looks like this image.
[image]

I want essentially three sections of the menu: a centered logo, a left side of menu items, and a right side of menu items. The dotted boxes denote those sections.

On the left section, I need two rows of menu items, that have even spacing dependent on the size of the box (spacing denoted by red lines). The spacing is also the same on the right section.

If someone could point me in the right direction or provide html/css, it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution using only flexbox:

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/b5a8294dae7969c4c9fa7cfca470626c

HTML:

```
<header class="global-header" role="banner">
  <nav class="global-nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="list global-nav__list">
      <li class="list__item global-nav__list-item"><a class="global-nav__link" href="">Service 1</a></li>
      <li class="list__item global-nav__list-item"><a class="global-nav__link" href="">Service 2</a></li>
      <li class="list__item global-nav__list-item"><a class="global-nav__link" href="">Service 3</a></li>
      <li class="list__item global-nav__list-item"><a class="global-nav__link" href="">Service 4</a></li>
      <li class="list__item global-nav__list-item"><a class="global-nav__link" href="">Service 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="global-nav__logo" href="/"></a>
    <ul class="list global-nav__list">
      <li class="list__item global-nav__list-item"><a class="global-nav__link" href="">About</a></li>
      <li class="list__item global-nav__list-item"><a class="global-nav__link" href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.global-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.global-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.global-nav__list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.global-nav__list .global-nav__list-item {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.global-nav__list .global-nav__list-item:nth-child(1), .global-nav__list .global-nav__list-item:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.global-nav__list .global-nav__list-item:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  content: '';
}

.global-nav__link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #3cc7e3;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.global-nav__link:hover {
  color: #222;
}

.global-nav__logo {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-sm-5">
    
      <div class="row">
      
        <div class="col">
        Left Content 
        </div>
        
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        
         <div class="col">
        Left Content under
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-2">
      Image?
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <span class="float-right">Right Content</span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, i assumed you use bootstrap because of your Tags, if not then im sorry. This works and you should throw a look [at the Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) for more examples.

Edit: if you want sections inside those columns that is also easily doable just throw a look at the docs